# How to group items from cursor in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, cursor, grouping

**Intro.** Let say we have `Messages` collection. And every doc in that collection looks like this:

```
{
  createdAt: 1432018583531,
  message: 'Hello',
  username: 'chuk',
  chatId: '82rWv8bv4YbxEiCky'
}
```

It’s easy to render plain list of messages:

```
<template name="messages">
  {{#each messages}}
    {{> singleMessage}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
---
Template.messages.helpers({
  messages: function () {
    return Messages.find(selector, options);
  }
});
```

Output may look like so:

> - @chuk [May 18, 10:00 AM]: Hello
> - @geck [May 18, 10:01 AM]: Hi
> - @geck [May 18, 10:01 AM]: How R U?
> - @chuk [May 18, 10:02 AM]: Fine :-)
> - @chuk [May 19, 09:02 PM]: Hey?

**Question.** How to group messages by date and by author? How to transform output to something like this:

> May 18
>
> - @chuk, 10:00 AM
>   — Hello
> - @geck, 10:01 AM
>   — Hi
>   — How R U?
> - @chuk, 10:02 AM
>   — Fine :-)
>
> May 19
>
> - @chuk, 09:02 PM
>   — Hey?

**Thoughts.** The first idea is to use `.fetch()` and group messages imperatively by iterating them all:

```
<template name="messages">
  {{#each dateBlock}}
    {{#each messageBlock}}
      {{#each}}
        {{> singleMessage}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
---
Template.messages.helpers({
  dateBlock: function () {
    return makeDateBlocks(Messages.find(selector, options).fetch());
  },
  messageBlock: function () {
    return makeMessageBlocks(this);
  }
});
```

But I believe that’s a bad way, because `.fetch()` will cause recomputing all the data on every change. The growing list will slow down depending on the number of elements.

What is the best way to do such grouping? Hey, meteors? May be we need to insert delimiters and give special classes to the elements via jQuery depending on data-attributes in `afterFlush` callback? Or?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your messages within the `find` call to add `new_user` and `new_date` flags in your `Messages` document if the time or user has changed since the previous one:

```
Template.messages.helpers({
  messages: function () {
    var lastMessage = null;
    return Messages.find({chatId: this.chatId}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}, transform: function (messageItem) {
      if (!lastMessage || lastMessage.createdAt < messageItem.createdAt.setHours(0,0,0,0))
        messageItem.new_date = true;
      else if (lastMessage.username !== messageItem.username)
        messageItem.new_user = true;
      lastMessage = {username: messageItem.username, createdAt: messageItem.createdAt.setHours(0,0,0,0)}
      return messageItem;
    }});
  }
});
```

Then, in your template:

```
<template name="messages">
  {{#each messages}}
    {{#if new_date}}
      {{> messageDate}}
      {{> userAndTime}}
    {{else if new_user}}
      {{> userAndTime}}
    {{/if}}
    {{> singleMessage}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

This should work if those transform calls are blocking. I cannot find evidence that they do not.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a good way. Data should remain raw. Because some day you’ll want to change grouping rules. Also, you wont see such flags in any production-quality messaging API.

Comment: Yeah... Not many production-quality APIs using Meteor though :) this is the cleanest way I can think of while keeping smooth reactivity

Comment: I still upvoted you, as it screams bad practice. But if you look at meteor examples for various use cases, they often come with seemingly unnecessary data storage (like children counts...), which is justified as being "the meteor way": it's not efficient, but it's "clean". (keeps the codebase light and readable)

Comment: I edited my answer using `transform`, so that it would not modify the `Messages` collection... Not sure if `transform` is blocking though.